# LINQ query not returning all results due to null value on Entity Framework Core only

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have two rows of test data and am able to pull back the first row with no problems but can't get the second row to return. Digging around and testing shows that this is probably due to the `AppovedByID` column being `null` in the row that is not being returned. I have looked but can't figure out how to modify my `LINQ` query so it will return all rows even if the child table can't be linked in due to a null value.

The Query:

```
    public JsonResult ChangeOrders()
    {
        var ChangeOrdersList = _DbContext.ChangeOrders
                                         .Include(co => co.ApprovalStatus)
                                         .Include(co => co.ApprovedBy)
                                         .Include(co => co.AssignedTo)
                                         .Include(co => co.CreatedBy)
                                         .Include(co => co.CurrentStatus)
                                         .Include(co => co.Impact)
                                         .Include(co => co.Priority)
                                         .Include(co => co.ChangeType)
                                         .Select(co => new ChangeOrderListVM()
                                         {
                                             ApprovalStatus = co.ApprovalStatus.Name,
                                             ApprovedBy = string.Concat(co.ApprovedBy.FirstName, ' ', co.ApprovedBy.LastName),
                                             AssignedTo = string.Concat(co.AssignedTo.FirstName, ' ', co.AssignedTo.LastName),
                                             CreatedBy = string.Concat(co.CreatedBy.FirstName, ' ', co.CreatedBy.LastName),
                                             CurrentStatus = co.CurrentStatus.Name,
                                             DateApproved = co.DateApproved,
                                             DateCompleated = co.DateCompleated,
                                             DateCreated = co.DateCreated,
                                             DateStarted = co.DateStarted,
                                             EstimatedEndDate = co.EstimatedEndDate,
                                             EstimatedStartDate = co.EstimatedStartDate,
                                             ID = co.ID,
                                             Impact = co.Impact.Name,
                                             Name = co.Name,
                                             Priority = co.Priority.Name,
                                             Reason = co.ReasonForChange,
                                             Type = co.ChangeType.Name
                                         }).ToList();

        return Json(ChangeOrdersList);
    }
```

ChangeOrders:

```
public class ChangeOrder
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public short? ApprovedByUserID { get; set; }
    public byte ApprovalStatusID { get; set; }
    public short AssignedToUserID { get; set; }
    public short CreatedByUserID { get; set; }
    public byte CurrentStatusID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateApproved { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCompleated { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateStarted { get; set; }
    public DateTime EstimatedStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EstimatedEndDate { get; set; }
    public byte ImpactID { get; set; }
    public byte PriorityID { get; set; }
    public byte TypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ReasonForChange { get; set; }        

    [ForeignKey("ApprovalStatusID")]
    public ChangeApprovalStatus ApprovalStatus { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ApprovedByUserID")]
    public User ApprovedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssignedToUserID")]
    public User AssignedTo { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CreatedByUserID")]
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrentStatusID")]
    public ChangeStatus CurrentStatus { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ImpactID")]
    public ChangeImpact Impact { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PriorityID")]
    public ChangePriority Priority { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TypeID")]
    public ChangeType ChangeType { get; set; }
}
```

Users:

```
public class User
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public short ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string ADUserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
}
```

EDIT:
This is apparently unique to Entity Framework 7 (AKA Core) as it works fine in EF 6. I am in fact using EF7 and as an additional test I updated a single line

```
ApprovedBy = string.Concat(co.ApprovedBy.FirstName, ' ', co.ApprovedBy.LastName),
```

and changed it to this

```
ApprovedBy = "",
```

and all the rows are returning so I then tried to do

```
ApprovedBy = (co.ApprovedByUserID.HasValue) ? string.Concat(co.ApprovedBy.FirstName, ' ', co.ApprovedBy.LastName) : "",
```

but that give a very odd error:

> incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'

Comment: Can't duplicate. Tried with EF6.1.3 and it works as expected (does `LEFT JOIN` for `AppovedByID` columns)

Comment: @IvanStoev I was just looking at an old project that used EF6.1 and it worked there. I am actually using EF 7 in this project so this looks to be something to do with EF  7 and LINQ. I will make an edit on that.

Comment: try using `(co.ApprovedByUserID.HasValue) ? (co.ApprovedBy.FirstName==null?"":co.ApprovedBy.FirstName+" "+ co.ApprovedBy.LastName==null?"":co.ApprovedBy.LastName) : "",`

Comment: @Viplock That gets rid of the syntax error but does not fix the main problem of the rows with a null for AppovedByID column.

Comment: Try using `(co.ApprovedBy != null) ? (co.ApprovedBy.FirstName + " " + co.ApprovedBy.LastName) : ""`

Comment: @FrankFajardo That only returns the row with an ApprovedByID assigned as well.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete, what happens if you just try `ApprovedBy = co.ApprovedBy.FirstName + ' ' + co.ApprovedBy.LastName,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in the library. I have reported the bug for fixing in the next version on [github](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4523)